# Connecting multiply clients to jabber account

Tags: jabber, xmpp

I'd like to connect multiply clients to single jabber account. I know that XMPP is well design and as far as I understend it is possible.

- GNU/Linux (empathy 2.31.91 and in future later) should receive all messages regardless if it is online or offline (i.e. messages should wait till empathy is connected). if it would help - empathy connects via telepathy
- Windows/mobile/... should receive messages only if they are connected on-line

I'm particularly interested in how to do first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meant this [XEP, which describes message archiving](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html).